# MS exchange outgoing transport rule using custom webservices

Tags: web-services, email, exchange-server

Problem:

I have over 30k users that, for the sake of argument, may like Dogs, Cats, Birds, and/or Mice.

The idea is to have users be able to mail each other but if the subject line contains the word "Dog" then anyone who is not a Dog person will not receive it.

Example:

```
User   Likes 
----   -----
Amy    Dogs, Cats 
Bob    Dogs, Birds 
Carl   Cats, Birds, Mice 
Dana   Mice 
Fred   Dogs, Mice
```

If Amy sends an email to everyone and the email has the word "Dog" in the subject line then only Bob and Fred should receive the email.

The actual scenario uses over 20 different "likes" which makes for a very large number of combinations, so I don't think a Distribution List will help here. But there is a web service that I can use which will tell me if a given user belongs to a given group, if I can use that before the email is distributed.

I'm hoping to have an outgoing transport rule reference the web service, but I couldn't find examples of that, so I'm not sure if it can be done or not.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Transport Rule that will allow you to call a WebService you might want to look at using a Transport Agent https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012(v=exchg.150).aspx and try to include all your logic within the Transport Agent rather then doing a web service call which can be costly in terms of Transport on a busy server.